# Chartist.js React Module not showing plot

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-react, chartist.js

I'm using Chartist.js library via the `react-chartist` npm package in a Meteor.js app to plot some data.

**Problem:** The Chartist graph shows only the axes but not the line plot! Did I something miss out?

**Rendered Component**

[image]

**Chart.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';


export class Chart extends Component {
    render() {
        var data = {
            labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            series: [[1,2,3,4,5]]
        }

        const type = 'Line';

        return (
            <div>
                <ChartistGraph data={data} type={type} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**packages.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "chartist": "^0.10.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
    "react-chartist": "^0.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including their CDN in your root HTML file if you haven't already. You can find it in the docs or here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist

They mention that the Chartist.js CSS code is not included in the react-chartist package but they leave the above scripts to add to your app. Otherwise you may have to manually style your chart in order to render it.